# Open source fuzzy logic library

Tags: c++

I need to implement AI for game based on fuzzy logic. I need to evaluate position of tower defense game and I have couple rules and I will add more. Can anyone suggest me some open source fuzzy logic library in c++ or code examples ?

Comment: Check out the C++ Fuzzy Logic Programming Library (https://sourceforge.net/projects/cpp-fuzzy-logic/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Free Fuzzy Logic Library (FFLL) ...

http://ffll.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

fuzzylite: http://code.google.com/p/fuzzylite/

> fuzzylite is a multiplatform, free, and open-source Fuzzy Logic Control Library written in C++ and released under the Apache License 2.0, which makes this software freely available for commercial and non-commercial use. The idea behind this library is to have a very simple and light-weight fuzzy controller. Simple as in simple to use, simple to understand, and simple to extend, without sacrificing performance.

Answer (score 0):

C++: [FuzzyLite](http://code.google.com/p/fuzzylite/)

Java: [JFuzzyLogic](http://jfuzzylogic.sourceforge.net/html/index.html)

Comment: https://github.com/kmilo17pet/qlibs for C and https://github.com/kmilo17pet/qlibs-cpp for C++