# resources for ffll free fuzzy logic library

Tags: fuzzy-logic

following the recommendation at [which fuzzy logic library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145253/open-source-fuzzy-logic-library)

I also have chosen to use this library, ffll. However, it seems the community for this library does not exist or too few programmers using this library and it's hard to get simple support.

For example, to write the FCL language to define (.fcl) fuzzy model, the language reference have to be purchased. Now, I simply want to write a model with two outputs but have no idea how to (the old reference guide don't compile). Or even to define some constants in that .fcl file

I've googled but failed.

Anyone's experience and comment is a big help to me!
Thank you

Comment: a sort-of fcl editor may also help a lot

Comment: I've found one community at sourceforge http://sourceforge.net/p/ffll/discussion/105110/

Comment: I think sourceforge discussion board is good enough for me. Current problems are resolved